# Firebase - Analytics: User engagement graph not showing screen_view events

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, capacitor

I have an app connected to FirebaseAnalytics. I can see that I am sending the screen_view event, and that it is arriving (as is the user_engagement event); but this isn't resulting in the scores appearing in the userEngagement dashboard.

Is there another property that has to be set for the dashboard to show user engagement?

As the events are arriving at Firebase I'm not sure it's relevant but just for completeness I am using @capacitor-community/firebase-analytics on iOS. This is reporting success in the console.

```
2020-11-07 16:32:28.016270+0000 Development[4563:1132540] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023105] Event is not subject to real-time event count daily limit. Marking an event as real-time. Event name, parameters: screen_view (_vs), {
    ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    ga_event_origin (_o) = app;
    ga_previous_class (_pc) = /info;
    ga_previous_id (_pi) = -3144803485867826237;
    ga_previous_screen (_pn) = /info;
    ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
    ga_screen (_sn) = /welcome;
    ga_screen_class (_sc) = /welcome;
    ga_screen_id (_si) = -3144803485867826236;
}
2020-11-07 16:32:28.038535+0000 Development[4563:1132540] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023087] User property set. Name, value: lifetime_user_engagement (_lte), 6215573
2020-11-07 16:32:28.038767+0000 Development[4563:1132540] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023087] User property set. Name, value: session_user_engagement (_se), 703736
2020-11-07 16:32:28.042258+0000 Development[4563:1132793] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS012018] Saving bundle. size (bytes): 532
2020-11-07 16:32:28.042885+0000 Development[4563:1132793] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023116] Bundle added to the upload queue. BundleID, timestamp (ms): 102, 1604766746929
2020-11-07 16:32:28.048243+0000 Development[4563:1132793] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023039] Measurement data sent to network. Timestamp (ms), data: 1604766748047, <APMPBMeasurementBatch: 0x2808f90c0>
2020-11-07 16:32:28.052526+0000 Development[4563:1132540] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS900000] Uploading data. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
2020-11-07 16:32:28.116422+0000 Development[4563:1132793] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901006] Received SSL challenge for host. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
2020-11-07 16:32:28.168702+0000 Development[4563:1132948] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023044] Successful upload. Got network response. Code, size: 204, -1
2020-11-07 16:32:28.173503+0000 Development[4563:1132948] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): -0.2433141469955444
2020-11-07 16:32:28.180798+0000 Development[4563:1132948] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled
```

[image: Screenshot showing events and the Screen_class view]
[image: Screenshot showing events and the Screen_name view]
[image: DebugView]

Answer (score 1):

I also agree with Martin, Firebase analytics updates data for 24h, this is actual for collecting data in a/b tests

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else who ends up spending hours debugging this - it's just a processing delay... in the morning (24hours later) the engagement graph has updated.
Do not adjust your screens ;)